# DIV position issues

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to position my DIVs as below

Logo / Menu / Social

Intro-left / intro-right

backpicture

Middle-1

bottom-left / bottom right

The issue is that for the moment DIVs are displayed like this (see JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A4Sn8/1/ ):

Logo / Menu

Social

backpicture

Intro-left / intro-right

Middle-1

bottom-left

bottom right

In summary, my "social" DIV is below the menu instead of on its right. Bottom-right DIV is under bottom-left instead of on its right and backpicture is before Intro-left and intro-right instead of after.

How could I fix this?

Many thanks

HTML

```
 <div id="logo">Logo</div>  <!-- End DIV Logo -->
  <div id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu I</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">Biography</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Publications</a> </li>
        </ul>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu 2</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">Demo</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Features</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Comparison</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu 3</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">Item 1</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Item 2</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Item 3</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu 4</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">ddfd</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">dsfd</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>  <!-- End DIV Main Menu -->
 <div id="social">Social</div>

    <div id="intro-left"></div>

    <div id="intro-right">
    <div id="content-headline"><h1>Novitates autem si spem</h1></div>  <!-- End DIV Content headline-->
      <p>Novitates sit.</p>

    </div> 

<div id="backpicture">backpicture</div>
<div id="middle-1">Middle-1</div>
<div id="bottom-left">bottom-left</div>
<div id="bottom-right">bottom-right</div>
```

CSS:

```
@charset"UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

Html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 20px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* mainmenu */

#mainmenu {
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mainmenu ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
    list-style: none;
}
#mainmenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
#mainmenu>ul>li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#mainmenu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#mainmenu ul li a, #mainmenu ul ul:hover li a {
    color: #333;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -ms-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -o-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -webkit-transition-property: all, -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: all, -moz-transform;
    -ms-transition-property: all, -ms-transform;
    -o-transition-property: all, -o-transform;
    transition-property: all, transform;
}
#mainmenu ul ul li a:hover, #mainmenu ul ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #005EBC;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -ms-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -o-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -webkit-transition-property: all, -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: all, -moz-transform;
    -ms-transition-property: all, -ms-transform;
    -o-transition-property: all, -o-transform;
    transition-property: all, transform;
}

social {
    right: 10px;
    Color: blue;
}

p {
    color: #333;
    font-weight:300;
    font-size: 13px;
}
h1 {
    color: #00539E;
    font-size: 30px;
    }



#intro-left {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
}

#intro-right {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
    width: 60%;
}
#backpicture {
    height:160px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

#middle-1 {
    width: 980px;
    background: #c81919;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#bottom-left {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    background: #5421c2;
}

#bottom-right {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
    width: 60%;
    background: #2ec4a6;

}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve

Comment: [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear; What I meant is that for the moment my "social" DIV is below the menu instead of on its right. Bottom-right DIV is under bottom-left instead of on its right, etc

Comment: Would prefer not to use bootstrap for this - tks anyway

Comment: Greg, with 87 questions behind you, I'm sure you can do better with **Question-Formatting**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mainmenu and social to be in one line:

```
#social {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 35px;
    right: 10px;
    color: blue;
}
#mainmenu {
    float:left;
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The main issue was `width:100%` given to `#mainmenu`. This didnt allowed `social` block to come to its right. Moreover specifying `float:left` in `#mainmenu` and `float:right` in `social` did the trick.

One more thing, your `social` in css didnt had `#`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing CSS rules with absolute pixel sizes and percent. That is not always a good idea.

You might have this problem, because your `padding-right` of 50px is larger than the remaining 5% of free space.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I guess the bottom elements should be on the same height. Try this:

```
#bottom-right {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 5%; /* you defined 50px instead! */
    width: 60%;
    background: #2ec4a6;
}
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/A4Sn8/2/

Comment: Thanks Smamatti. It did fix the issue of bottom-right not being positioned next to bottom left. Would you know what to change in order to have #social to the right side of #mainmenu and why backpicture (the div with blue background) is positioned before intro-left and intro-right instead of underneath? Many thanks

Comment: OK, I fixed the 2nd point with clear:both in my #backpicture DIV. Just can't get the social DIV to the right of the menu

Comment: @Greg Seeing that there is an accepted answer, I guess this is no longer needed?